# How to add variable to path

Tags: python-3.x, filepath

How do I insert correctly the "username" variable instead of "yamaman" in the path line?
This is the relevant code lines:

```
def setUp(self):
username = input('Enter your Windows username:')
preferences = {"download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\yamaman\Desktop\myfolder"}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be something like:

```
preferences["download.default_directory"] = preferences["download.default_directory"].replace("yamaman", username)
```

If your `preferences` dictionary is created after you get input from username you could simply do:

```
preferences = {"download.default_directory": fr"C:\Users\{username}\Desktop\myfolder"}
```

It is up to you how you validate input